# <f:facet> tag not rendered

Tags: jsf, xhtml, facet

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{run.runList}" var="eachRun"
        columnClasses="columnRun" id="runList">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="run_header">
                <h:outputText value="Environment-Application-Department-StartTime"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:commandLink action="#{run.runChosen}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{run.chosenRunID}"
                    value="#{eachRun.testRunID}" />
                <h:outputText value="#{eachRun.toString()}" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

This block of code is within a `<ui:define>`
The column of command links is rendered just fine. However, the `<f:facet>` is not rendered. I tried to inspect element in the produced page. There is not even a `<tr>` before the first command link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<f:facet name="header">` instead of `<f:facet name="run_header">`

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-datatable-example/